# Javascript function execution order

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and have a quick question. Say i have the following code:

```
function entryPoint()
{
   callFunction(parameter);
}

function callFunction(parameter)
{
   ... //do something here
   var anotherFunction = function () { isRun(true); };
}
```

My question is that when `callFunction(parameter)` is called, and the variable `anotherFunction` is declared, does `isRun(true)` actually execute during this instantiation? I am thinking it doesnt and the contents of the anotherFunction are only "stored" in the variable to be actually executed line by line when, somewhere down the line, the call `anotherFunction()` is made. Can anyone please clarify the function confusion?

Comment: You're right, it won't be executed in that example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems the confusion is this line of code

```
var anotherFunction = function () { isRun(true); };
```

This declares a variable of a function / lambda type.  The lambda is declared it is not run.  The code inside of it will not execute until you invoke it via the variable

```
anotherFunction(); // Now it runs
```

Comment: Here's the style for an "immediately executing anonymous function." `var anotherFunction = ( function () { isRun(true); } )();`

Answer (score 4):

You almost described it perfectly.

`anotherFunction` just receives a reference to a newly created `Function Object` (yes, Functions are also Objects in this language) but it does not get executed.

You could execute it by calling

```
anotherFunction();
```

for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a simple test like so:

```
entryPoint();

function entryPoint()
{
    alert("In entryPoint");
    callFunction();
}

function callFunction()
{
    alert("In callFunction");
    var anotherFunction = function () { isRun(); };
}

function isRun()
{
    alert("In isRun");
}
```

​
And, the answer is no, isRun() does not get called.